# Read a file Line by Line with a condition

Tags: android

So I have a .txt File like this :

```
Name: James
Phone number: 1111111
age: 50
```

I want to read this file line by line and every time I put this line in a map. So in the end I want to have a map with keys=name,phone number,age and values=James,111111,50.
I have a code which reads a file but not with that condition.
Can someone help me please

this code is not really mine.

```
    File file;
    byte[] buffer = null;
            InputStream is;
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(file);
                int size = is.available();                 
                buffer = new byte[size]; 
                is.read(buffer); 
                is.close(); 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        String str_data = new String(buffer);
    }
```

Comment: Does your file contain multiple such entries or just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily if its a JSON file. But considering what you have asked I would suggest an approach like this.

```
public HashMap<String,String> getMap(String pathToFile){
    FileInputStream inStream=new FileInputStream(pathToFile);
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

    //create a hashmap
    HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap();
    //enter empty values (Not exactly necessary)
    //you can enter default values if you like
    map.put("name",null);
    map.put("age",null);
    map.put("number",null);

    String line;
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
        //when doing the following its good to check whether lastIndexOf() returns -1
        if(line.startsWith("Name:")){
           String name=line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(":")+1;
           //you can additionally remove starting and ending spaces if you want.
           //I do that only here.
           map.put("name",name.trim());
        }else if(line.startsWith("Phone Number:")){
           String number=line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(":")+1;
           map.put("number",""+number);
        }else if(line.startsWith("age:")){
           String age=line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(":")+1;
           map.put("age",""+age);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help but they say BufferedReader cannot be applied to FileInputStream

Comment: thank you for the update, but it keeps saying cannot resolve method subString

Comment: Sorry dont consider my last comment

Comment: It has to be `substring`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this using a Scanner to read all your data, put this data in a HashMap as key value and them return the value of the HashMap with the key you are looking for:

```
public String getPreferencesByKey(String key){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"YOUR TXT FILE"));

    HashMap<String,String> preferences = new HashMap<String,String>();

    scanner.useDelimiter(":");
     //Get all the data from the file
     while (scanner.hasNext()&&running) {
        String data = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] line = data.split(":")
        if (line.length > 1) {
            variablesToBeParse.put(line[0],line[1].trim);
        }
    }

    return preferences.get(key);

}
```

Or return all the HashMap and handle in other way in your code:

```
public HashMap<String,String>getPreferencesFile(){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"YOUR TXT FILE"));

    HashMap<String,String> preferences = new HashMap<String,String>();

    scanner.useDelimiter(":");
     //Get all the data from the file
     while (scanner.hasNext()&&running) {
        String data = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] line = data.split(":")
        if (line.length > 1) {
            variablesToBeParse.put(line[0],line[1].trim);
        }
    }

    return preferences;

}
```

Depend what you really need, although I recommend you using SharedPreferences instead of your own file:

**Get data:**

```
SharedPreferences settingsPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);
 settingsPreferences.getString("Name", "");
 settingsPreferences.getString("Phone number", "");
 settingsPreferences.getInt("age", "");
```

**Set data:**

```
 SharedPreferences settingsPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settingsPreferences.edit();
 editor.putString("Name","Your name");
 editor.putString("Phone number","Your phone number");
 editor.putInt"age",27);
 editor.commit();
```

You can find more info about SharedPreferences here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: thanks for the help, but I want to use my own file because when I change the name for exemple, I dont want to use my code, I just want to edit my .txt file.

Comment: In this case check the first part of the post.

Comment: To use your own file use the first solution using a Scanner to open your file

Answer (score 0):

You can read file by using buffered reader,but in buffered reader readLine() whenever a \n character will come that much it will read in single shot.also it will not return the \n character so we need to add \n while reading

```
File file1=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/abc.txt");
try {
FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(file1);
BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);
content=bufferedReader.readLine();
StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder(content);
while((content=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
   stringBuilder.append("\n"+content);
}
content=stringBuilder.toString();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String[] temp=content.split("\n");
HashMap<String,String> valuesMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] keyValue;
for(String value:temp){
  keyValue=value.split(":");
  valuesMap.put(keyValue[0],keyValue[1]);
}
```